# NameError in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So I'm working on a web app using rails and the google cloud datastore. I'm relatively new at coding web apps. Most of the errors I'm running into come from trying to integrate the datastore with the rails MVC model. For further context most of my code is based of the Google Datastore Bookshelf tutorial found on the datastore information page. https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore

So recently I ran into a NameError in PostsController#create when I was trying to save a post to the datastore database. I can't seem to find the cause of this issue so hopefully someone can be my new set of eyes or provide some insight.

Also if you know any places where I can find helpful documentation using datastore and rails. That would be appreciated

**So this is my post_controller.rb file**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  PER_PAGE = 10

  def index
     @post, @cursor = Post.query limit: PER_PAGE, cursor: params[:cursor]
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new post_params

    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted"
      redirect_to posts_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
      end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
      end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
      end

end
```

**This is my model for the post post_rb**

```
require "google/cloud/datastore"

class Post
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :title, :body

    # Return a Google::Cloud::Datastore::Dataset for the configured dataset.
     # The dataset is used to create, read, update, and delete entity objects.
        def self.dataset
        @dataset ||= Google::Cloud::Datastore.new(
        project: Rails.application.config.
                     database_configuration[Rails.env]["dataset_id"]
    )


end

# Query Book entities from Cloud Datastore.
#
# returns an array of Book query results and a cursor
# that can be used to query for additional results.
def self.query options = {}
  query = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Query.new
  query.kind "Post"
  query.limit options[:limit]   if options[:limit]
  query.cursor options[:cursor] if options[:cursor]

  results = dataset.run query
  posts   = results.map {|entity| Post.from_entity entity }

  if options[:limit] && results.size == options[:limit]
    next_cursor = results.cursor
  end

  return posts, next_cursor
end

  # [START from_entity]
def self.from_entity entity
  post = Post.new
  post.id = entity.key.id
  entity.properties.to_hash.each do |name, value|
    post.send "#{name}=", value if post.respond_to? "#{name}="
  end
  post
end
 # [END from_entity]

  # [START find]
  # Lookup Book by ID.  Returns Book or nil.
  def self.find id
    query    = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Key.new "Post", id.to_i
    entities = dataset.lookup query

    from_entity entities.first if entities.any?
  end
  # [END find]


 # [START validations]
  # Add Active Model validation support to Book class.
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :title, presence: true

  # [END validations]

  # Save the book to Datastore.
# @return true if valid and saved successfully, otherwise false.
def save
  if valid?
    entity = to_entity
    Post.dataset.save entity
    self.id = entity.key.id
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

end
```

**This is my new.html.erb file that i use to call the save method in datastore**

```
<h1>Create Post</h1>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <div class="alert alert danger"><%= msg %></div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label:title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field(:title, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label:body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area(:body, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
    </div>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**This is my routes.rb file**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :main, only: [:show]

  resources :posts

  root to: 'posts#index', as: "home"


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

EDIT: Forgot to include the error message log

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `to_entity' for #<Post:0x65b0d70>
Did you mean?  to_key):

app/models/post.rb:72:in `save'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

NOTE: The create.html.erb is blank so I choose not to include it

Comment: Please post the full error message including the filename and line number in which the error occurred. The stack trace might be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you are missing a `to_entity` method. Try adding something similar to this for your post model. I slightly modified the code from the `Book` documentation example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-ruby/blob/master/2-cloud-datastore/app/models/book.rb#L95). You will want to read that entire file to see what their Book model looks like with all of the code.

```
def to_entity
  entity                 = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Entity.new
  entity.key             = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Key.new "Post", id
  entity["title"]        = title
  entity["body"]         = body
  entity
end
```

Comment: Well actually I don't I can use ActiveRecord because it conflicts nosql database setups. So I didn't include it when I created the app.

Comment: I edited my response now that you posted a stack trace

Comment: NameError (undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Post:0x9d5d9f8>):

app/models/post.rb:40:in `to_entity'
app/models/post.rb:80:in `save'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:16:in `create'

Comment: That was the new error I got, but I'm assuming your answer is putting me in the right direction.

Comment: You will want to add an `id` to the attr_accessors in your model. i.e. `attr_accessor :id, :title, :body`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I think looking at the screen all the time made me miss these errors.